# Boot2Docker: Can't create directory: Protocol Error

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

Trying to learn Docker in a windows machine. When I was trying create a new directory inside the shared User folder (/c/Users) by executing `sudo mkdir sample` but getting an error saying `Can't create directory 'sample': Protocol Error`.

Any pointers to resolve this issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox does mount automatically `C:\users` (see [VirtualBox Guest Additions](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/README.md#virtualbox-guest-additions)), but that does not mean you can create anything directly in C:\Users ([not without Administrative privilege](https://superuser.com/q/330699/141), and `sudo` don't apply here)

You can create anything you want in your own folder: `C:\Users\mylogin`

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to create a new directory inside `C:\users\site`, same error occurs!

Comment: @Raathigesh Are you logged in as user/account "site" though? And did you used sudo? If yes, try without sudo.

Comment: When I login as "site" I can create directories. Thanks a lot! You saved me a lot of time :)